# Style Radio Buttons with CSS3 ::before and ::after

Tags: html, css

I am working on the front end of a web project. To fit the design of the website, I want my radio buttons to look like these:

[image: nice radio buttons]

So I headed over to [this nice article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) and started reading, so that I may implement this myself. I have gone ahead and created the three icons above in illustrator and saved them to my web project.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<section>
    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="person" id="radio-btn-james" value="James" checked>
        <label for="radio-btn-james">James</label>
    </div><!-- .radio -->

    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="person" id="radio-btn-michael" value="Michael">
        <label for="radio-btn-michael">Michael</label>
    </div><!-- .radio -->

    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="person" id="radio-btn-andy" value="Andy">
        <label for="radio-btn-andy">Andy</label>
    </div><!-- .radio -->
</section>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
section {
    padding: 50px;
}

/* RADIO BUTTON STYLING */

.radio-btn {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio-btn {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

.radio-btn,
.radio-btn + label::before {
    content: url('radio_unchecked.png');
}

.radio-btn:checked + label::before {
    content: url('radio_checked.png');
}

.radio-btn:hover,
.radio-btn:hover + label::before {
    content: url('radio_hover.png');
}

.radio label {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

But I'm getting weird behavior! I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txDG6/5/) of what I have.

**PROBLEMS:**

1. Radio buttons won't tick (icon doesn't change).
2. As I hover, icon changes for the wrong radio button, not the one I hovered over!

Comment: element id's should be unique in html and label `for` attribute should point to this unique id. (this solves problem 2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will solve it: http://jsfiddle.net/hf8Ux/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<section>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="person" id="radio-1" value="James">
            <label for="radio-1">James</label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="person" id="radio-2" value="Michael">
            <label for="radio-2">Michael</label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="person" id="radio-3" value="Andy">
            <label for="radio-3">Andy</label>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.radio input[type=radio] {
   visibility: hidden;
}   
.radio input + label::before {
    content: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/k9umie.png');
    margin-right:5px;
}

.radio input:checked + label::before {
    content: url('http://i62.tinypic.com/5mjspc.png');
}
.radio input:hover + label::before {
    content: url('http://i62.tinypic.com/kasc5k.png');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any element's id should be unique in HTML and a label element's `for` attribute should point to a id. (this solves problem 2.)

So HTML should look like:

```
  <section>
    <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="person" id="person_1" value="James" checked>
            <label for="person_1">James</label>
        </div><!-- .radio -->

        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="person" id="person_2" value="Michael">
            <label for="person_2">Michael</label>
        </div><!-- .radio -->

        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="person" id="person_3" value="Andy">
            <label for="person_3">Andy</label>
        </div><!-- .radio -->
    </section>
```

Problem 1 is a bit more complicated but it has to do with they way you created the selectors.

`#radio-btn, #radio-btn + label` means apply this css to any element with the  `#radio-btn` id and also (second rule seperated by comma) apply it to the label that is directly after this element. so this does not achieve the effect you desire. You want to only target the label that is directly after a radiobutton. you can do this by using: `input + label` or more specific `input[type='radio'] + label`